# PHP removing empty lines before inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, string, str-replace

I have a string that Im retrieving from xcode that contains some coordinates, when the string is inserted into the database it shows as:

```
(
    "37.351701,-122.105898",
    "37.351945,-122.106109",
    "37.352183,-122.106338"
)
```

I need the string to be:

```
37.351701,-122.105898,
37.351945,-122.106109,
37.352183,-122.106338
```

Im using str_replace, it removes the () but an empty line is left:

```
//empty line
37.351701,-122.105898,
37.351945,-122.106109,
37.352183,-122.106338
//empty line
```

The code Im using, how can I remove the empty lines?

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
@mysql_select_db($db) or die("Unable to find database");
$trackArray = $_GET["trackArray"];

$trackArrayOutput = str_replace( array('"', '(' , ')', ' ', '\n', '\r', '\n\r'), '', $trackArray);

$query = "INSERT INTO routes VALUES ('', '$trackArrayOutput')";

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error"));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: use the trim() function in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n\r` is not a valid line ending; you mean CRLF - `\r\n`. `trim()` is also very useful for removing beginning/trailing white-space and line breaks:

```
$trackArrayOutput = str_replace( array('"', '(' , ')'), '', $trackArray);
$trackArrayOutput = trim($trackArrayOutput);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$myvar = " cool huh ?     ";

//trim it
$myvar = trim($myvar);

//now echo
echo $myvar ;  //result will be  

cool huh?
```

Answer (score 2):

You've come across a **PHP gotcha**.

Change your replacement from:

```
array('"', '(' , ')', ' ', '\n', '\r', '\n\r')
```

to:

```
array('"', '(' , ')', ' ', "\n", "\r")
```

`'\n'` doesn't give you the `newline` character. You need the `"` to have PHP evaluate the string.

For clarification: `var_dump('\n' === "\\n"); // true`

---

Note that the output will be:

```
37.351701,-122.105898,37.351945,-122.106109,37.352183,-122.106338
```

so everything is on one line.

Comment: Didn't notice this. +1

Comment: This doesn't produce the result OP was looking for.

Comment: Neither does George's solution - the indenting for the first line will be missing. I would argue using a proper serialization, either `serialize` or `json_encode` would be a better solution in general.

Answer (score 1):

CRLF won't work when between single quotes.

To replace them, use : "\r\n" not '\r\n'.

Here is a dirty hack that can help too :

```
function noNl($string){
    return str_replace("<br />","",nl2br($string));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$trackArray = trim($_GET["trackArray"]);
$query = "INSERT INTO routes VALUES ('', '$trackArrayOutput')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the problem into different steps:

```
// convert all newlines to '\n'
$str = str_replace( array("\n","\r","\r\n"), "\n", $str);

// remove first line
$str = substr($str, strpos($str, "\n")+1 );

// remove last line
$str = substr($str, 0,strrpos($str, "\n")-1);

// remove the spaces
$str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/108403)

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is platform dependent: the platform of the PHP host, not the platform of the source file. Since it doesn't seem logical to assume anything it's probably best to replace all combinations.